# gccのバージョンを5.5にしたらglfw3.hを認識しなくなった

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, opengl

### こうなった経緯

macのgccで生文字列リテラルがエラーになったので、もしかしたらC++11に対応してなかったのかと思い、MacPortsを使ってgcc5をインストールしたところ、以前にHomeBrewでインストールしたglfw3をコンパイル時に認識しなくなってしまいました。これについて解決する方法はありますでしょうか？

### コンパイル時コマンド

```
terminal
$ gcc main.cpp -framework OpenGL -lglfw
main.cpp:1:24: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーに出ているのは`GLFW/glfw3.h`ですから、コンパイルの引数に指定するのは`-lglfw`ではなく`-lglfw3`になりませんか？
もしくはインクルードパスにヘッダファイルが存在するディレクトリを`-I`オプションで明示的に指定してやる方法もあります。もし`/path/to/include/GLFW/glfw3.h`にファイルがある場合は

```
$ gcc main.cpp -framework OpenGL -I/path/to/include -lglfw
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。両者コマンド試してみましたが動かないですね...同じエラーが出てしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

brewでインストールしたglfwでなく、サイトからソースコードをダウンロードし、Cmakeからmakefileでライブラリ作成し、それがあるパスを表記したところ、コンパイルが通りました。

あんまり腑に落ちないですけど......